# Transfering data to REST API without a database django

Tags: python, django, rest, api

Basically I have a program which scraps some data from a  website, I need to either print it out to a django template or to REST API without using a database. How do I do this without a database?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to

a.) Perform the scraping in views themselves, and pass the info in a context dict to the template

or

b.) Write to a file and have your view pull info from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Django can be run without a database, but it depends on what applications you enable. Some of the default functionality (auth, sites, contenttypes) requires a database. So you'd need to disable those. If you need to use them, you're SOL.

Other functionality (like sessions) usually uses a database, but you can configure it to use a cache or file or something else.

I've taken two approaches in the past:

1) Disable the database completely and disable the applications that require the database:

```
DATABASES = {}
```

2) Use a dummy sqlite database just so it works out of box with the default apps without too much tweaking, but don't really use it for anything. I find this method faster and good for setting up quick testing/prototyping.

And to actually get the data from the scraper into your view, you can take a number of approaches. Store the data in a cache, or just write it directly to your context variables, etc.